# How to parse an xml file using Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, xml-parsing

I want to parse an XML file in Excel VBA.

The xml file looks like this:

```
<Dummy docType="GetToken" copyright="Copyright Dummy Inc." versionNumber="1.7" createdDate="2018-09-25T13:03:36Z" statusId="0" statusText="" responseId="e1c967ec-607c-4cd0-94f1-8eee5f506c93">
   <AuthResponse>
         <AuthToken expiry="2018-09-25T14:02:00Z">ABCDEF123</AuthToken>
         <ServerPath>site.Dummy.com/traffic/Dummy.ashx</ServerPath>
         <ServerPaths>
               <ServerPath type="API" region=“X">http://eu.api.Dummy.com/Dummy.ashx</ServerPath>
          </ServerPaths>
    </AuthResponse>
```

I want to parse the AuthToken value to use in a subsequent call.

The current code.

```
Sub GetToken()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Worksheets("APICallInfo")
Dim strURL As String
strURL = ws.[TokenURL]

Dim hReq As New WinHttpRequest
hReq.Open "Get", strURL & "&Vendorid=" & VendorID & "&Consumerid=" & ConsumerID
hReq.Send

Dim strResp As String
strResp = hReq.ResponseText

Dim xmlDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
Set xmlDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
If Not xmlDoc.LoadXML(strResp) Then
    MsgBox "Load Error"
End If

Dim Token As IXMLDOMNode
Set Token = xmlDoc.FirstChild

Debug.Print Token.SelectSingleNode("AuthToken").Text

End Sub
```

I receive a message saying 'Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range'.

Comment: On what line do you get the error?

Comment: If I start a new file, add MSXML6 reference, and parse your `dummy xml` **without** the `<Dummy docType="GetToken" ...` line (not a valid XML declaration, so with it I'll always hit the load error msgbox) everything executes perfectly. In other words - It's not the XML parsing itself. Have you checked whether the `strResp` is properly populated / whether the request actually works?